# How to choose specific table with specific page in Spire documents?

Tags: java, ms-word, spire.doc, spire

iam useing Spire Doc library to create word templete SO,

in the below example , 1st table in page-1 has been chosen to make find and replace operation ,,,

i created word documents like these but i need to choose 1st table in Page-2

,,, Thanks in advance for your support
[Output Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFfv0.png)
[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCoY0.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFfv0.png)

```
import com.spire.doc.*;  
import com.spire.doc.documents.Paragraph;  
import com.spire.doc.documents.TextSelection;  
import com.spire.doc.fields.DocPicture;  
import com.spire.doc.fields.TextRange;  
import java.util.HashMap;  
import java.util.Map;  
  
public class CreateByReplacingPlaceholderText {  
    public static void main(String []args){  
        //Load the template document  
        Document document = new Document("PlaceholderTextTemplate.docx");  
        //Get the first section  // What is Section Means in Word , and how can i select section in word ?
        Section section = document.getSections().get(0);  
        //Get the first table in the section  
        Table table = section.getTables().get(0);  
  
        //Create a map of values for the template  
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
        map.put("firstName","Alex");  
        map.put("lastName","Anderson");  
        map.put("gender","Male");  
        map.put("mobilePhone","+0044 85430000");  
        map.put("email","alex.anderson@myemail.com");  
        map.put("homeAddress","123 High Street");  
        map.put("dateOfBirth","6th June, 1986");  
        map.put("education","University of South Florida, September 2013 - June 2017");  
        map.put("employmentHistory","Automation Inc. November 2013 - Present");  
  
        //Call the replaceTextinTable method to replace text in table  
        replaceTextinTable(map, table);  
        // Call the replaceTextWithImage method to replace text with image  
        replaceTextWithImage(document, "photo", "Avatar.jpg");  
  
        //Save the result document  
        document.saveToFile("CreateByReplacingPlaceholder.docx", FileFormat.Docx_2013);  
    }  
  
    //Replace text in table  
    static void replaceTextinTable(Map<String, String> map, Table table){  
        for(TableRow row:(Iterable<TableRow>)table.getRows()){  
            for(TableCell cell : (Iterable<TableCell>)row.getCells()){  
                for(Paragraph para : (Iterable<Paragraph>)cell.getParagraphs()){  
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {  
                        para.replace("${" + entry.getKey() + "}", entry.getValue(), false, true);  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
  
    //Replace text with image  
    static  void replaceTextWithImage(Document document, String stringToReplace, String imagePath){  
        TextSelection[] selections = document.findAllString("${" + stringToReplace + "}", false, true);  
        int index = 0;  
        TextRange range = null;  
        for (Object obj : selections) {  
            TextSelection textSelection = (TextSelection)obj;  
            DocPicture pic = new DocPicture(document);  
            pic.loadImage(imagePath);  
            range = textSelection.getAsOneRange();  
            index = range.getOwnerParagraph().getChildObjects().indexOf(range);  
            range.getOwnerParagraph().getChildObjects().insert(index,pic);  
            range.getOwnerParagraph().getChildObjects().remove(range);  
        }  
    }  
  
    //Replace text in document body  
    static void replaceTextinDocumentBody(Map<String, String> map, Document document){  
        for(Section section : (Iterable<Section>)document.getSections()) {  
            for (Paragraph para : (Iterable<Paragraph>) section.getParagraphs()) {  
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {  
                    para.replace("${" + entry.getKey() + "}", entry.getValue(), false, true);  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
  
    //Replace text in header or footer  
    static  void replaceTextinHeaderorFooter(Map<String, String> map, HeaderFooter headerFooter){  
        for(Paragraph para : (Iterable<Paragraph>)headerFooter.getParagraphs()){  
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {  
                para.replace("${" + entry.getKey() + "}", entry.getValue(), false, true);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "page" definition in Spire.Doc because MS Word documents are actually "flow" documents. But there might be a way to achieve what you want, that is to set a title for each table in the Word template (right-click on the table->Table properties->Alt text->Title), then loop through the tables in the section, and find the desired table by its title using **Table.getTitle()** method.